# Representing an ip prefix-list in Python using pytricia, ipaddress, or any other library

Tags: python, networking

Trying to represent an ip prefix-list in python using pytricia or ip address, yet neither of them behaves properly when it comes to checking whether a prefix exists in a prefix-list or not

```
ip prefix-list PFXLST seq 10 permit 0.0.0.0/0
ip prefix-list PFXLST seq 20 permit 172.16.0.0/12
ip prefix-list PFXLST seq 30 permit 192.168.0.0/16
```

to represent and check against like this...

```
>>> from ipaddress import ip_network
>>> from pytricia import PyTricia
>>>
>>> prefix_list = PyTricia()
>>> [prefix_list.insert(subnet, "permit") for subnet in ["0.0.0.0/0", "172.16.0.0/12", "192.168.0.0/16"]]
[None, None, None]
>>> ip_network("10.0.0.0/8") in prefix_list
True
```

On the other hand

```
>>> [prefix_list.insert(subnet, "permit") for subnet in ["172.16.0.0/12", "192.168.0.0/16"]]
[None, None]
>>> ip_network("10.0.0.0/8") in prefix_list
False
```

Any idea why the condition returns `True` in the first case?! and if there's an alternative to doing this, please!

Appreciate the help! :)

Comment: Every IPv4 address is in the `0.0.0.0/0` network. Every IPv4 network is a subnet of the `0.0.0.0/0` network. That is why a routing table entry of `0.0.0.0/0` is a default route (route of last resort) because it will be the shortest match, and longer matches are preferred in a routing table, but `0.0.0.0/0` will match any address if there are no matches that are longer.

Answer (score 1):

I am not one-hundred percent clear on how pytricia is processing the `in` operator, however...

if `pytricia` is expected to see whether a subnet is present in another subnet, then... be aware that `0.0.0.0/0` is the Quad-Zero Route and is essentially a subnet that contains all other subnets.

Thus if `0.0.0.0/0` is in the `prefix_list` and if `pytricia` is checking to see if a given subnet (i.e. `10.0.0.0/8`) is wholly included within any of the subnets within the `pytricia` `prefix_list`, then presumably, any prefix list that contains the Quad Zero Route will automatically include all other subnets and will always return `True`.

## As an example:

If I create a smaller `prefix_list` without the Quad Zero Route and then check to see if a given subnet (i.e. `172.16.0.0/13`) is wholly contained in that prefix_list, then we get `True`, as expected, because the given subnet is contained within `172.16.0.0/12`.

```
>>> for subnet in ["172.16.0.0/12", "192.168.0.0/16"]:
    prefix_list.insert(subnet, "permit")

>>> ip_network("172.16.0.0/13") in prefix_list
True
```

Comment: Sorry if I didn't make my question clear; I'm asking about the condition, not filling in the list

    >>> ip_network("10.0.0.0/8") in prefix_list
    True

in the first case versus

    >>> ip_network("10.0.0.0/8") in prefix_list
    False

in the second case

Comment: @zigzag thanks for the clarification. I revised the answer completely. Please take a look and see if this provides some insight into what your code is doing.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this.  I understand now the behaviour of pytricia a little more clearly, yet this is not how prefix-lists' logic filter subnets, and I'm looking into writing something to represent the prefix-list, then I pass it a prefix to check if it's permitted or denied.  Do you happen to know something to do this?

and again, thanks so much for the help here :)

Comment: A solution might be to read in lines from the config file & for any rule that is a "permit" rule, create a matching subnet within the `pytricia` tree. Thus, anything that matches when `pytricia` checks to see if a subnet falls within a list of known good subnets, would pass > however > given that the config file lists the `0.0.0.0/0` rule as permitted, this will break your system & essentially permit all subnets. NOTE: it feels like this is becoming a new question. If the answer above is adequate to answer your first question, please accept the answer & consider submitting a new question.

Answer (score 0):

The alternative you're looking for is `has_key()`.

From the pytricia documentation:

> The has_key method is also implement, but it's important to note that the behavior of in differs from has_key. The has_key method checks for an exact match of a network prefix.

As E. Ducateme said correctly, the `in` operator checks if the prefix is 'covered' in the trie. What you're looking for is `has_key()`, which checks for an exact match.